# Django default at database

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, django-1.9

So as I recently came to understand, the `default` that we specify in a Django field is merely for filling up pre-existing rows, and doesn't function as a "real" default value at the database level. This can be verified by looking up `column_default` from the database shell.

If I understand correctly, `default` is used by Postgres to put in values when there is no input. If that is so, then we shouldn't be able to create a new object in Django without providing the default value, right?

For ex -

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True) # new field added
```

For the above model, the `default` is used for only backfilling the newly added field for pre-existing rows. It doesn't actually set a default at the database level.

```
 column_name | column_default                                     
-------------+----------------
 mymodel     |
```

But if that is so, I shouldn't be able to run this query -

```
MyModel.objects.create(name='test')
```

since there's no "real" default. But I can, and I don't understand why.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting docs:

> The default value is used when new model instances are created and a value isn’t provided for the field. When the field is a primary key, the default is also used when the field is set to None.

Default works at application level, not at database level. I mean, when new model instance is created (in memory) default value is applied there is not an explicit value provided.

`Default` is not translated to ddl ( database data definition language ) as `not null` or `unique` do.

Notice that `default` may be a value or, alseo, may be a django function that is invoked when new model is created to provide a value.

Because all this, **the default field value will not be present on database schema.**

**Edited 2023**

Use the new [db_default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-default) for database-computed default value (credits to [@sytech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5747944/sytech), see comments)

Comment: Yes, this is huge architectural issue in Django.

Comment: This is weird. Any idea why they did this?

Comment: @SohamDongargaonkar, because is not trivial to translate random python code to any brand of  database code (t-sql, pl-sql, ...)

Comment: There's an accepted ticket for this in django with a good chance of making it to django 5.0 https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470

Comment: wow @digenishjkl, keep us on the loop, please!

Comment: This is [now implemented](https://github.com/django/django/commit/7414704e88d73dafbcfbb85f9bc54cb6111439d3) in the development version of Django with the [db_default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-default) keyword.